# Log all queries that mgo fire in the application

Tags: go, mgo

How to log every query with mgo in standard output?
I set logger but it shows a lot of information without actual queries.

Answer (score 4):

An answer from Gustavo Niemeyer, author of mgo : http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mgo-users/152571ky82/how-to-show-query-log#20150209zwzki7mxjfigdzuqp245wskkl4

> There are two ways you can handle this issue:
>
> 1. By enabling MongoDB logging
>
>    This is independent from the driver (mgo in this case), and can be
>      enabled in the shell or by running the respective command via mgo:
>
>    http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/
> 2. By enabling mgo logging
>
>    You can do this by creating a Logger via the standard package's
>      log.New function and providing it to mgo's SetLogger function:
>
>    http://golang.org/pkg/log/#New, http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2#SetLogger
>
> Use mgo.SetDebug to increase the verbosity:
>
> http://gopkg.in/mgo.v2#SetDebug

So if you already have the Logger set, enable the debug mode.

Comment: Note, method #2 will only capture queries issued by that instance of the Go Mongo client. It will not capture queries issued by other Mongo clients.

Comment: This didnt work for me. I can see a lot of output from mgo but I do not see the query.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get mgo to log queries using SetLogger and SetDebug. Instead, I solved this by marshaling to json string and then printing:

```
q = bson.M{}
jsonString, _ := json.Marshal(q)
fmt.Printf("mgo query: %s\n", jsonString)
```

You can also copy/paste the output of this into a standard mongo client if you need to debug a query.